# Is there water in my forks?

Tags: maintenance, fork, downhill

Hi I bought a used downhill bike with a 2009 Marzoochi 66RCV fork. I hear a gushing sound whenever I compress the forks. At first I thought it was oil but am just wondering and don't want to ruin anything. Is there anything i can do besides taking apart the fork. Thank you for any answers.

Comment: If you don't know the service history, its worth doing a service anyway. Not sure about Marzoochi but most brands suggest a service interval between 20 and 50 hours riding.

Comment: Whooshing and squelching from oil damped forks is not unusual. But like mattnz says, just get it serviced, water in it is unlikely, but old, dirty oil and seals are very likely.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is most likely oil moving through the valves. If you are concerned about more water getting into the fork you could clean out your fork seals with a piece of old camera film.

Given the year of the fork, I suggest taking it to your local bike shop. It cannot hurt to service your fork and support the people that support riding in your area!